# res.render proper way to pass locals argument

Tags: express, ejs

I have next code in my navbar.ejs:

```
  <% if (isIndex) { %>
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Todos</a></li>
    <% } else { %>
        <li><a href="/">Todos</a></li>
    <% } %>
    
    <% if (isCreate) { %>
        <li class="active"><a href="/create">Create</a></li>
    <% } else { %>
        <li><a href="/create">Create</a></li>
    <% } %>
```

And in my routes file i have two routes '/' and '/create':

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => { res.render('index', { title: '"To do" list', isIndex: true }) })
```

and

```
router.get('/create', (req, res) => {
const options = {
    title: 'create new "to do"',
    isCreate: true,
}

res.render('create', options)
```

I have special flag depending on what page is it (either index or create) and make corresponding `<li>` active. But I am getting "isCreate is not defined" error with either passing it as obj literal (route '/') or passing it as var options (route '/create'). What does work is passing like this:
`res.render('path', { options })` and in ejs use `<% if (options.isIndex) { %>`  and `<% if (options.isCreate) { %>`. But why?